# XSLT: Output text of current node only and normalize whitespace

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an xml document with the below structure. I'm writing a transformation where I'd like to output the text from node B but ignore the element C and text node "title". Essentially I'd like to extract the text "text goes here" and output it in a new element with all the whitespace normalised. Can anybody help? The below is what I've tried so far.

```
Input Doc
<A>
  <B>
    <C>title</C>
     text goes here
  </B>
</A>

Required output doc
<d>text goes here</d>


Solution A:
<xsl:template match="B">
  <d>       
    <xsl:copy-of select="./text()"/>                
  </d>
</xsl:template>
```

Problem: the whitespace between elements is preserved so I get something like this:

```
<d>

  Text goes here

</d>
```

I also tried using a value-of statement (`<xsl:value-of select="./text()"/>`) in the template in solution A but this didn't return any text at all. Is there something wrong with the statement?

I should mention that I have overridden the the default text handling template using the following: `<xsl:template match="text()" />`

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The reason `<xsl:value-of select="./text()"/>` returned "nothing" is that `./text()` will return a node *set* consisting of all the immediate child text nodes of the current node.  The `value-of` a node set is the string value of its *first* item, which in this case is the whitespace-only text node between the opening `<B>` and the opening `<C>` tags.  The same applies to the next-most-obvious `normalize-space(text())` because that again converts the node set to a string (the first node value) and then normalizes space in that string.  Instead, you need to normalize each child text node individually:

```
<d>
  <xsl:for-each select="text()">
    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/>
  </xsl:for-each>
</d>
```

One thing to note about this though is that if you have input like

```
<A>
  <B>
    <C>title</C>
     text goes here
    <C>subtitle</C>
     more text here
  </B>
</A>
```

then you will get output of

```
<d>text goes heremore text here</d>
```

with no space between the bits either side of the subtitle.  If this is a problem you can use a trick like

```
<d>
  <xsl:for-each select="text()[normalize-space(.)]">
    <xsl:if test="position() &gt; 1"><xsl:text> </xsl:text></xsl:if>
    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/>
  </xsl:for-each>
</d>
```

to iterate over only those text node children that contain non-whitespace characters, and add a space before all but the first of them.

```
<d>text goes here more text here</d>
```

Answer (score 0):

The closest I get is with a select of [the `child` axis](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#axes): `//B/child::text()`.

The `child` axis will only return text nodes that are direct children of the current context node, so it will not match the `title` node.

Comment: Hey Frank! Can you please post the complete working code?? I tried using `B/child::text()` and `value-of select="normalize-space(.)"` and someother combinations but seems like it doesn't work for me..

Comment: I couldn't get this to work either. The full template would be helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this code!

Instead of using `<copy-of>` I have used template override!

1. I replace B by D..
2. I drop `<C>` from output. That solves half of the problem, So text of `<C>` node doesn't appear in output.
3. I apply normalize-space function to all text nodes .. so extra whitespace will be wiped off :)

here is the code:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
        <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
      <xsl:template match="B">
        <d>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
        </d>
      </xsl:template>

      <xsl:template match="C"/>

      <xsl:template match="text()">
        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/>
      </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```